# Add a "loading" indicator in a MVC webgrid?

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3, loading, webgrid

I am using MVC3 and displaying my data in a webgrid. I would like to display loading indicator (loading image) displayed when I filter/search. What is the best approach?

My search filter (code):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     <fieldset  id="fieldset1" class="coolfieldset">

        <legend>Search for Towers Watson Subscribers/Contacts</legend>
        <div class="div-table">
        <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col">Reg Date:</div>
            <div class="div-table-col"><input id="regDateFrom" class="datepicker" name="regDateFrom" value="@regDateFrom" type="text" /> to <input id="regDateEnd" class="datepicker" value="@regDateEnd" name="regDateEnd" type="text" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col">Profile Mod Date:</div>
            <div class="div-table-col"><input type="text" id="profileModDateFrom" class="datepicker" value="@profileModDateFrom"  name="profileModDateFrom" /> to <input id="profileModDateEnd" class="datepicker" value="@profileModDateEnd" name="profileModDateEnd" type="text" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col">Last Name:</div>
            <div class="div-table-col"><input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="@lastName" /></div>
        </div>
          <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col"><input id="search" name="search" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
            <div class="div-table-col"></div>
        </div>
        </div>      
    </fieldset>
}
{@Html.Partial("List_Ajax", Model)}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.ajaxload.info/ lets you create a nice loading gif. Create an image, and place it in a div as below. Then bind the search button with jQuery to display the hidden div when clicked.

Place the following div where you would like the loading icon to appear.

```
<div id="loadingDiv" style="display:none"><img src="loading.gif"></div>
```

Then this in your Javascript file

```
$(document).ready(){
    $('#search').click(function(){
        $('#loadingDiv').show();
    });
});
```

Then when you're done loading, simply:

```
function SomeCallBackEvent(){
    $('#loadingDiv').hide();
};
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!

Comment: @RyanAmies For us n00bs here, how does one generally know when loading is complete given that items are being added to the grid? Could you provide a simple example to extend this answer? Thank you.

Comment: It really depends on your code. If you're loading it with jQuery/Ajax then you will have a callback for `Complete` which you can leverage. If you're stuck I'd suggest posting a new question specific to your situation.